# Create 2 end points in OWIN

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api2

I have scenario, where there are 2 type of users. On type of user (Admin), I need to do azure  authentication and for external users, I need to do Database validation. Currently I am able to authenticate user either by DB or either by Azure using OWIN /token with single Web API. How can we handle 2 authentication with single api and 2 end points using OWIN. Please tell me is there any better way to do this.

Thanks,
Raj

Comment: I assume that you want your app to recognize the user account type and redirect them to different authenticate endpoint right?

Comment: Yes Wayne Yang. should redirect to either of endpoint, one end point is for Azure AD Authenticating and other end point for SQL DB authentication.

Comment: I understand that. However, I think that it should be build in your Application.  BTW, why not sync all users to azure ad and manage it :-)

Comment: Users are 2 types : Admin user who are in Azure AD, External user who will register and do normal DB authentication, for this we use OWIN /token end point, but how to handle for Azure end point

Comment: Hi Wayne Yang, Is there any way for 2 end points in OWIN, or we need to expose two different end points by creating 2 Web API projects.